# How can I change color / backgroundColor of list item in nativescript-vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to update selected item style when user taps on items. nextIndex/event.index is updated but style doesn't apply. Thanks for your help.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ihH3iO

```js
export default {
  name: "CustomListView",
  props: ["page", "title", "items", "selectedIndex"],
  data() {
    return {
      nextIndex: this.selectedIndex ? this.selectedIndex : undefined
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onItemTap(event) {
      this.nextIndex = event.index;
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.selected {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ListView for="(item, index) in items" @itemTap="onItemTap">
    <v-template>
    <Label :class="['list-item-label', { selected: index == nextIndex }]" :text="item" />
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground?

Comment: @Narendra I updated the question with a playground URL, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More info about this [issue](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/316).

> This is expected behavior because the ListView's item template is rendered and updated by the list view when scrolling (view recycling) if you need to make sure the list view is updated when you change your property, call refresh on it.

**So the solution is**

```html
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ListView v-for="(item, index) in items" @itemTap="onItemTap" ref="listView">
            <v-template>
                <Label :class="[{selected: index === nextIndex}, 'list-item-label']"
                    :text="item" />
            </v-template>
        </ListView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "CustomListView",
        data() {
            let selectedIndex = 2;
            return {
                items: ["Bulbasaur", "Parasect", "Venonat", "Venomoth"],
                nextIndex: selectedIndex
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onItemTap(event) {
                this.nextIndex = event.index;
                this.$refs.listView.nativeView.refresh();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

You need refresh your `listView` the code for that is `this.$refs.listView.nativeView.refresh();`

Don't forget to add the `ref` on the `<ListView>`

Comment: Thanks Steven, you code works nicely. However I would like to ask if there's any shortcomings of forcing the list refreshing every taps. As I found that this could also be achieved by itemLoading & setting the cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor without refreshing the list.

Comment: what a surprise!

Comment: Can you show me where you found that about the `itemLoading & setting the cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor`?

Comment: @Steven Here the solution I found.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335252/make-a-nativescript-listview-transparent-on-ios