# Change background color of selected item in ListView in Nativescript-vue

Tags: listview, nativescript-vue

I'm looking to change the background color of a selected item in a ListView in Nativescript-vue.  Presently when I click an item it "flashes" gray as if its been selected but immediately reverts back to a white background.

My end-goal is to have a list that the user can scroll thru, select an item, and then click an "edit" button. The visual cue for what item has been selected is critical.

Rendering:

```html
<template>
    <page class="page" >

        <ActionBar class="action-bar">
            <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Manage Accounts"></Label>
        </ActionBar>

        <StackLayout>
            <Button text="Add" />

            <ListView for="account in accountsList" @itemTap="onItemTap" class="h2" style="height:150px">
                <v-template>
                    <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
                        <Label :text="account.name" />
                    </FlexboxLayout>
                </v-template>
            </ListView>

            <!-- <ListPicker :items="accountsList" v-model="selectedItem" /> -->
            <Button text="Edit" @tap="tapEdit" />
            <Button text="Return" @tap="returnButton" />
        </StackLayout>
    </page>
</template>
```

Method:

```js
onItemTap(event) {
                    const itemIndex = event.index;
                    // this.accounts[event.index].bgColor = "#3489db";
                    console.log(itemIndex);
                }
```

Digging further thru the stacks, I encountered this issue / solution - [How can I change color / backgroundColor of list item in nativescript-vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281319/how-can-i-change-color-backgroundcolor-of-list-item-in-nativescript-vue/57291185#57291185) , which seems exactly like what I'm looking to do.  I lack sufficient points for posting a comment, but if someone knows how Louis solved the problem that would likely be ideal. Following his linked solution results in specifics for Ios in a more traditional NS app, and I am only mildly familiar with the NS-vue flavor presently.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

After many countless hours sitting upon the same issue, found the solution.
I was workng with `RadListView` while i encountered the problem

### Problem

How to set backgroundColor or any property for that matter while the item is selected.

### Solution

The `onItemTap` event argument have more properties than it would seem otherwise namely,

- item
- eventName
- object
- index
- view

Same is true for `RadListView` `itemSelected / itemDeselected` events. 
There you go. All the problems are solved when you see the `view` property. 
For example you can set
`view.color = #ff0000`

PS: It seems that `RadListView` stores the state of selected item and reverts it back on deselection if we don't set any styles. Havn't checked for `ListView` though.